# Clockwork not logging to Heroku console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, clockwork

I am using the Clockwork gem to run a series of rake tasks. All looks good, but it seems the `puts` commands dont appear in the logs, and was just wondering if anyone had any idea why?

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',        __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'clockwork'

include Clockwork

module Clockwork
    configure do |config|
        config[:max_threads] = 30
        config[:thread] = true
    end

    error_handler do |error|
        Airbrake.notify_or_ignore(error)
    end

    handler do |job|
        Rails.logger.info "Enqueuing job: '#{job}'"
    end

    every(60.seconds, 'Test Job') {
        `rake testing_clockwork`
        }

end



desc 'Testing Clockwork'
task :testing_clockwork => :environment do

    puts "Testing Clockwork"

    Rails.logger.info("Testing Clockwork")


end
```